# Get all records that "own" all of these other records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Recipe` model that has_many `Ingredients` through `RecipeIngredients`:

```
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
```

*RecipeIngredient model with recipe_id and ingredient_id columns.:*

```
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
```

**My question is, how do I get all recipes that have all of a number of specific ingredients?**

---

Attempt:

*Recipe model:*

```
scope :by_ingredient, -> ing { includes(:recipe_ingredients).where(recipe_ingredients: {ingredient_id: ing.id})}
```

When I do `Recipe.by_ingredient(apple)` it correctly returns all recipes that have apples and `Recipe.by_ingredient(orange)` correctly returns all recipes that have oranges.

But when I chain the scope like so: `Recipe.by_ingredient(apple).by_ingredient(orange)`, it returns an empty array even though there are recipes that have apples AND oranges.

Comment: In `Recipe.by_ingredient(apple).by_ingredient(oranges)` is oranges a single object or a collection?

Comment: And does `Recipe.by_ingredient(oranges)` also return an empty array?

Comment: @AnthonyE Sorry, I meant to say `Recipe.by_ingredient(apple).by_ingredient(orange)`. Also, `Recipe.by_ingredient(orange)` does successfully return all recipes that have oranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after hours of searching I found the method [merge](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge):

```
Recipe.by_ingredient(apple).merge(Recipe.by_ingredient(orange))
```

which successfully returns all recipes that have apples and oranges.